# Create a new contract from other contract by connecting to ganache-cli

Tags: solidity, ganache

I am trying to create a contract from other contract on gnache-cli using remix web3 provider but getting following error:

```
VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

The issue is that when I try it on the JavaScript VM (on remix), I am not getting any error. Kindly note that I am running ganache-cli with the following parameters:

```
ganache-cli -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8545 -l 3000000000
```

As a sidenote, I am able to deploy the contract... the problem appears only when deploying from another contract. In the ganache-cli console, I am getting this error:

```
Transaction: 0x1f77d94278c27412affe6be5f7bd50d6f95d47503fa6c302553e1a94cfb7111c
Gas usage: 2250998
Block Number: 3
Block Time: Fri Sep 28 2018 13:33:14 GMT+0400 (+04)
Runtime Error: revert
```

Version of tools used:

- ganache-cli 6.1.8 (ganache-core: 2.2.1)
- solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface: 0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.Linux.g++
- npm: 6.4.1

Contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test2{
    constructor() public{

    }
}

contract Test{

    function createInstance() public{
        address test2 = new Test2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gas limit estimated in a wrong way(because of internal smart contract deployment), the transaction needs more gas than it was estimated by metamask(web3). If you increase gas limit the transaction will pass.